# Can you provide rights to a snapshot without providing rights to the database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, snapshot

Is it possible to give a user or group rights to a snapshot without giving them rights to the database if the database and snapshot both reside on the same instance?

Answer (score 3):

From [Limitations and Requirements of Database Snapshots](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189940(v=sql.105).aspx) on TechNet:

> A database snapshot inherits the security constraints of its source database at the time of snapshot creation. Because snapshots are read-only, inherited permissions cannot be changed and permission changes made to the source will not be reflected in existing snapshots.

**Update:**

As [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) suggested in a comment, one way is to grant permissions on database, take a snapshot, and then remove permissions. The login could be temporarily disabled for the period that rights were granted.